# Is it allowed to pause outgoing call until an action is chosen from AlertDialog?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-call

I created a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for outgoing calls. My idea was to detect the outgoing call, open `AlertDialog` asking a user to "initiate some action" or to continue outgoing call. Based on user's choice, outgoing call would continue or the call would be stopped and some action (open another `Activity`) would be initiated.

I have issues finding a way to "freeze" outgoing call until a user chooses something. The `AlertDialog` appears, but the outgoing call continues.

So I would like to know:

1. Is it allowed to freeze outgoing call in this manner?
2. If Q1 is yes and a user chooses to open an `Activity`, how do I cancel outgoing call? Using `setResultData(null)` does not help in this case as the call is still initiated with NULL to call.

Comment: I don't think you can do this, it would interrupt the connection that your device is trying to make, and I don't think there is a way to consistently understand how you are interrupting this (like lifecycle methods) which would lead me to believe this wouldn't be a doable thing. Again, assumptions based on the little I know about the background process.

Comment: @zgc7009 I see other apps have this. I open the native contacts on a regular android, I touch to call someone, and a popup from that app appears saying something like "do you want to proceed with a regular call or make a call with this app". So it is possible. I only cannot freeze this call as in my case it continues and does not wait for me to press some button

Comment: I believe that is different, at that point it hasn't tried to create the connection, it is simply asking how you would like to make the connection. Those are  two different situations.

Comment: @zgc7009 Any ideas how to first call this popup and then possible conduct a call? Whatever I tried, I could not stop the device from calling someone.

Comment: Yea, look into intent choosers. Make one for ACTION_CALL